# Summing infinite series 1/n

Tags: c#

I just started taking my first steps in learning coding and general (starting with c#)and I'm learning from a book currently. The book leaves questions at the end of every chapter. I'm currently unsure on how to proceed with this specific question. The question is as follows:

**Question: Write a program that calculates the sum (with precision of 0.001) of the following sequence: 1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 + … 1/n**

The book has given the following guidelines for this problem:

**Guide Lines: Accumulate the sum of the sequence in a variable inside a while-loop (see the chapter "Loops"). At each step compare the old sum with the new sum. If the difference between the two sums Math.Abs(current_sum – old_sum) is less than the required precision (0.001), the calculation should finish because the difference is constantly decreasing and the precision is constantly increasing at each step of the loop. The expected result is 1.307**

I have an idea on how to implement this but I do not know how or where to initiate and break the loop when the sum has reached the required precision. I currently use user input to enter n. I would like to know how to automate this process.

Here is my code so far. I know its a cop out to use the format {N:2} but i am not sure how to proceed. Would very much appreciate the help! Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Console.Write("Please enter n: ");
        double counter = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double sum = 1 + AddSum(counter); // calculate infinite sum 
        Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0:N3}", sum);



    }


    static double AddSum(double n)
    {
        double a = 0;

        for (double i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                a -= 1 / (i +1); // calculates negative fractions
            }

            else
            {
                a += 1 / (i +1); // calculates positive fractions
            }
        }

        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the criteria for program completion?It's not a number entered by a user. It Is "If the difference between the two sums Math.Abs(current_sum – old_sum) is less than the required precision (0.001), the calculation should finish". Then you return the result. So you should not be asking the user to enter n

Comment: I was unsure how to begin to solve the problem thus i decided to ask input from user. My hope was that I would be able to print out the initial sum first and then work out the rest of the problem with regards to the required precision.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that doesn't suffer from [subtractive cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance):

```
static double AddSum()
{
    double pos = 1.0;
    double neg = 0.0;

    double delta = 0.001;
    double current = pos + neg;
    double previous = pos + 2.0 * delta;

    int i = 2;
    while (Math.Abs(current - previous) >= delta)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            pos += 1.0 / i;
        }
        else
        {
            neg -= 1.0 / i;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = pos + neg;

        i++;
    }

    return current;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of delta? I do not understand the line where it says                                                    double previous = pos + 2 * delta

Comment: @Nate - That's to ensure that the expression `Math.Abs(current - previous) >= delta` is true.

Comment: @Nate - Sorry, I had an error in the code. I replaced the `0.001` in the condition of the `while` loop with `delta`.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to follow the given guideline: don't enter n as the program shall finish automatically. Where is the suggested while loop? You'll figure the answer out quickly yourself then :-)

Maybe start with this:

```
static void Main()
{
    decimal result = 1;
    int n = 1;
    do
    {
        // remember the current result
        result += 1 / (++n * DetermineMultiplier(n));
    } while ( /* precision calculation here */ );

    // print result and n
}

private int DetermineMultiplier(int n)
{
   // return -1 if n is odd, 1 if it is even
}
```

Comment: This approach suffers from subtractive cancellation errors. You should always sum the positive and negative terms separately.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Please elaborate and/or edit the answer. I left the precision calculation open so your comment doesn't apply.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance & https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Weaknesses/

Comment: The issue isn't with the precision calculation, but the sum of the series. It should be computed as `1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6 + ...) - (1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + ...)` and not `1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 + 1/6 - 1/7 + ...`.

Comment: Thanks! The above example is to help the OP further, not to provide a full solution.

Answer (score -1):

As you not want to specify `n` and the only exit condition is a precision check, you could do this.

```
static double AddSum()
{
    double a = 0;
    double oldvalue;
    int i = 1;

    do
    {
        oldvalue = a;
        a += (i % 2 == 0) ? (double)-1 / (i + 1) : (double)1 / (i + 1);

        i++;
    }while (!(i != 1 && Math.Abs(a - oldvalue) < 0.0001)); // we can remove i!=1  if we know and hard code first default value

    return a; 
}
```

Working [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qOalGQ)

Comment: This approach suffers from subtractive cancellation errors. You should always sum the positive and negative terms separately.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I don't understand exactly what you mean? could you please elaborate? we can improve the answer.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance & https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Weaknesses/